# Java smart locking mechanism

Tags: java

I have some code that needs to lock in a very smart way.
Let's say I need to lock a code section that does some http request that basically updates some text file.

This operation can work on a given file by its name.

My pseudocode:

```
public void UpdateFile(int id){
     dal.invokeHTTPutRequest(id, fileContent);
}
```

I want this code to be **synchronized/lock** in a way that

1. the locking will happen only for the given id. So if id 1 is requested and then another request to id 1 is requested it will wait. But if a request to id 2 will arrive it will not wait.
2. I want some timeout so if many requests arrive and so it takes a lot of time they will get an exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's common in distributed lock implemented by database or cache(such as redis) or some other quorum middleware(such as zookeeper and ETCD)

Here provide a simple implementation without other middleware based on Guava:

import com.google.common.cache.*;

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockUtil {
    private static final LoadingCache<Integer, Lock> lockCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(Long.MAX_VALUE).build(new CacheLoader<Integer, Lock>()
            {
                @Override
                public Lock load(Integer i)
                {
                    return new ReentrantLock();
                }
            });

    public static Lock getLock(int id) throws ExecutionException {
        return lockCache.get(id);
    }
}
```

You can use ConcurrentHashMap Instead;

And for timeout, you can use tryLock(timeout) instead of lock()

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for you would be to use a HashMap of java ReentrantLock’s. In the hashmap you can use the file if as the key to retrieve the relavent reentrantlock.

Answer (score 0):

I tried string pool to get synchronized monitor object. Seems to be okay for me please comment on this implementation

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.concurrent.*;

  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
          List<Callable<String>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
          taskList.add(() -> abcd(1));
          taskList.add(() -> abcd(3));
          taskList.add(() -> abcd(1));
          taskList.add(() -> abcd(1));
          ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
          executor.invokeAll(taskList);
        }

        private static String abcd(int id) throws InterruptedException {
          synchronized (String.valueOf(id).intern()){
            System.out.println(id +" - "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Thread.sleep(2000l);
          }
          return String.valueOf(id);
        }

  }
```

hope you can use like this

```
    public void UpdateFile(int id) {
      synchronized (String.valueOf(id).intern()) {
        dal.invokeHTTPutRequest(id, fileContent);
      }
    }
```